# Register a Mailer Interceptor in Rails on just a single mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I'm trying to add an interceptor to one of several mailers in my Rails application. Even though I'm trying to register it on only a single mailer, it seems to be intercepting the emails from both. Here is some sample code of how I'm trying to register just a single Mailer.

```
class Mailer1 < ActionMailer::Base; end
class Mailer2 < ActionMailer::Base; end

Mailer1.register_interceptor(MailInterceptor)
```

Is it possible to follow just a single mailer? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is apply the interceptor only on specific Mailers:

```
class SpecificMailerInterceptor
  FILTERED_MAILERS = %w(SpecificMailer)

  def self.delivering_email(message)
    return if deliver?(message)

    message.perform_deliveries = false
  end

  def self.deliver?(message)
    # If you are in the other mailers always deliver message
    return true unless FILTERED_MAILERS.include?(message.delivery_handler.to_s)
    # Apply interceptor logic here       
  end
end
```